# Read and compare the value of CKRecord?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

Is there have any solution to read and compare the value of CKRecord? In a word, something like:

```
if valueOfRecord("Country") == "Taiwan" {
// code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Faster way**,

```
if (object("Country") as! NSString) == "Taiwan" {
// code
}
```

**Safer Way**

```
if let countryName = object("Country") as? NSString {
     if countryName == "Taiwan" {
      // code
     }
} else {
    // object("Country") in not a string type record
}
```

Comment: But the problem is -- I can't find what kind of real object I can put instead "valueOfRecord" ☹️

Comment: Use "object" . Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/3003386-object